# What platforms will my app that targets the .Net 3.5 framework run on?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm writing a C# app (in VS 2008). If I target the .Net 3.5 framework, will it run on Windows XP and above? Will XP users potentially have to download a .Net upgrade?

**UPDATE**

If the app is intended for business / corporate environments do you think it's pretty safe to target 3.5 rather than 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Windows 7 and newer will come with .NET 3.5 (SP1) pre-installed; Windows XP and Vista users, while able to run apps built on .NET 3.5, have to download and install it first in order to use your app.

I think the latest service packs of XP and Vista include .NET 3.5, though.

Answer (score 2):

> If the app is intended for business / corporate environments do you think it's pretty safe to target 3.5 rather than 2.0?

Not if the client machines are not able to upgrade or install the 3.5 Framework.

It's not safe to assume they already have the framework. It is realistic, however, to have them install the framework. They probably have it, and if they don't then they should get it if you're writing an app in 3.5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kirk Broadhurst. Very helpful.